# How to convert Google Earth KML to Raster with classes for Fragstats

Tags: raster, kml, land-cover, land-use, fragstats

I have digitized the Google Earth imagery for a 117 sq. km. area and have classified the land-use into forest and non-forest sites. I need to use this map for fragstats and calculation of landscape metrics. When I load the KML files into QGIS I don't get any information and I am stuck on how to go ahead with creating classes and creating a raster with forest and non-forest information.

I have looked into supervised and unsupervised classfication and the resolution obtained would not work very well for my study on forest fragmentation. I have also looked at land cover maps which are available for the region and they are not of use either.

How can I create a raster from a KML such that the raster contains class information?

Comment: I'm stuck on the expression "KML shapefile". Shapefile is a specific multi-file binary geodata format. KML is an XML text document with a geodata component. These are very different things. If you are using "shapefile" as an alias for "geodata", I suggest you avoid this in the future.

Comment: Thank you Vince. You are right... That is a mistake, what I imply is kml file.